# Are Viscous Resistance and Viscous force the same thing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, drag, viscosity, dissipation

Poiseullie’s Formula tells us about Viscous Resistance which confused me that if viscous force and viscous resistance are the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Drag (what you call resistance) is defined as the component of the force exerted on a body by the fluid in the direction of the free-stream velocity.

This force is the result of the integral of the stress on the surface of the body, the stress has both viscous and non-viscous (like those due to pressure) contributions.